# fop 2.1 Reached EOF when loading font on weblogic server

Tags: java, fonts, weblogic, truetype, apache-fop

I have a webapp that generates PDF files. I use fop 2.1 for this, but some characters are not in the default fop font. I try to use other font, to to print all characters correctly.

If I try it in a testclass, that I execute on my PC, everything works fine. But if the application try to do the same on the weblogic server, I receive:
java.io.EOFException: Reached EOF, file size=23275952 offset=23275954 error.

My fop configuration (I use the same for the test and for the application):

```
<fop version="2.1">
    <use-cache>false</use-cache>
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font embed-url="urkunde/ClearSans-Regular.ttf" kerning="yes">
                    <font-triplet name="ClearSans" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

The error I receive when the server try to load the font:

> Mar 24, 2016 1:07:33 PM org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.OpenFont
>   readPostScript SEVERE: Unknown PostScript format: 1912630528 Mar 24,
>   2016 1:07:33 PM org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont load SEVERE: Failed to
>   read font metrics file null java.io.EOFException: Reached EOF, file
>   size=23275952 offset=23275954     at
>   org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.FontFileReader.seekSet(FontFileReader.java:58)
>     at org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.TTFFile.readName(TTFFile.java:57)
>     at org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.OpenFont.readFont(OpenFont.java:740)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.OFFontLoader.read(OFFontLoader.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.OFFontLoader.read(OFFontLoader.java:93)
>     at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontLoader.getFont(FontLoader.java:124)     at
>   org.apache.fop.fonts.FontLoader.loadFont(FontLoader.java:108)     at
>   org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont.load(LazyFont.java:116)     at
>   org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont.getAscender(LazyFont.java:233)  at
>   org.apache.fop.fonts.Font.getAscender(Font.java:118)  at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockLayoutManager.initialize(BlockLayoutManager.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractLayoutManager.getChildLM(AbstractLayoutManager.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.FlowLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(FlowLayoutManager.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.FlowLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(FlowLayoutManager.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.getNextKnuthElements(PageBreaker.java:254)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.getNextBlockList(AbstractBreaker.java:752)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.getNextBlockList(PageBreaker.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.getNextBlockList(PageBreaker.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:388)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.doLayout(PageBreaker.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.activateLayout(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.endPageSequence(AreaTreeHandler.java:267)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence.endOfNode(PageSequence.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:360)
>     at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.endElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1101)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2939)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
>     at
>   weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
>     at
>   weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:484)

I have tried it with other font too. That worked well when I tested, but on the server I received NegativeArraySizeException.

I don't know what I am missing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Keep going with your analysis: what are the differences? Which versions of Java are installed on your machine and on the server respectively? How does the program get invoked? Is the font you use byte-for-byte identical (did you verify this with a crc, md5, sha1, or any other hash digest?) etc.

Comment: The decimal value "1912630528" is in hex `72006D00`, which does not look like a valid offset. At a glance, it could be Unicode (which is valid for a TTF font name) - there may be something wrong with the font file, OR the file gets translated to another encoding somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was, that the font was inside an ear and a war file. If the font is only on the server, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to skip ttf filtering in maven configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With this configuration you can keep ttf inside ear/war package.